# How can I marshal a hash with arrays?

Tags: ruby, serialization

What should I do to **marshal an hash of arrays?**
The following code only prints `{}`.

```
s = Hash.new
s.default = Array.new
s[0] << "Tigger"
s[7] << "Ruth"
s[7] << "Puuh"
data = Marshal.dump(s)
ls = Marshal.restore( data )
p ls
```

If the hash doesn't contain an array it is restored properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
s = Hash.new
s.default = Array.new
s[0] << "Tigger"
s[7] << "Ruth"
s[7] << "Puuh"
```

This code changes the default 3 times (which is probably what showed up in the dump), but it does not store anything in the hash. Try "puts s[8]", it will return [["Tigger"], ["Ruth"], ["Puuh"]].

A Hash.default_proc will do what you want

```
s = Hash.new{|hash,key| hash[key]=[] }
```

But you can't marshall a proc. This will work:

```
s = Hash.new
s.default = Array.new
s[0] += ["Tigger"]
s[7] += ["Ruth"]
s[7] += ["Puuh"]
```

This works because []+=["Tigger"]  creates a *new* array.
An alternative, creating less arrays:

```
s = Hash.new
(s[0] ||= []) << "Tigger"
(s[7] ||= []) << "Ruth"
(s[7] ||= []) << "Puuh"
```

Only creates a new array when the key is absent (nil).

Comment: works for me :-). a little bit more elegant than Julians append_to_hash so this is my answer.

Comment: Resetting the default would also work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818623/marshal-ruby-hash-with-default-proc-remove-the-default-proc

Answer (score 2):

You can just create your hash structure while initialing Hash.new to avoid such trouble

```
h = Hash.new{ |a,b| a[b] = [] }
h[:my_key] << "my value"
```

Comment: Great answer, this is by far better than my `append_to_hash`.

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me a "can't dump hash with default proc" error on marshaling. I guess thats because of the redefinition of [].

Comment: You need the `s.default = Array.new` or you'll get that error.

Comment: Ok, that works without error but gives me {} on restore again.

Answer (score 1):

You might be misled about how `Hash.default` works.

Before you `Marshal.dump`, print the data structure. It is `{}`. That's because you are concatenating each string into nil, not into an empty array. The code below illustrates and solves your problem.

```
s = Hash.new
s.default = Array.new
s[0] = []
s[0] << "Tigger"
s[7] = []
s[7] << "Ruth"
s[7] << "Puuh"
p s
data = Marshal.dump(s)
ls = Marshal.restore( data )
p ls
```

Returns:

```
{0=>["Tigger"], 7=>["Ruth", "Puuh"]}
{0=>["Tigger"], 7=>["Ruth", "Puuh"]}
```

**EDIT:**

> I insert a lot of data into the hash

So maybe some helper code would make the insertion process smoother:

```
def append_to_hash(hash, position, obj)
  hash[position] = [] unless hash[position]
  hash[position] << obj
end

s = Hash.new
append_to_hash(s, 0, "Tigger")
append_to_hash(s, 7, "Ruth")
append_to_hash(s, 7, "Puuh")
s.default = Array.new // this is only for reading
p s
data = Marshal.dump(s)
ls = Marshal.restore( data )
p ls
```

Comment: Printing the data dump from my example gives

    "\004\b}\000[\b\"\vTigger\"\tRuth\"\tPuuh"

so obviously the data is there but it cannot be used.
I tried to avoid a special clause on insertion because I insert a lot of data into the hash.

Comment: You can append elements using `+` instead of `<<` method, that way you don't need to initialize each new element.

Comment: Doesn't work here - gives the same result. Version is NetBeans with jRuby 1.8.6. Could you provide a running example?

Comment: edited version works for me. expected something cleaner though. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As you can't use `Marshall.dump` on a Hash with a proc for the default element, you could use a slightly more roundabout way of appending to each Array instead of `<<`:

```
s = Hash.new
s.default = []
s[0] += [ "Tigger" ]
s[7] += [ "Ruth" ]
s[7] += [ "Pooh" ]
data = Marshal.dump(s)
ls = Marshal.restore(data)
p ls
```