# is there a convenience way to build nested hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have several vars such as **year**, **month**, **day**, **hour**, **minute**. I need to do some operations on a nested hash with these values like `hash[2012][12][12][4][3]`. When meet a new date, I need to extend the hash.

I can do this by judging each level **one by one**, and create a hash if not exists. But I'm wondering there is a convenience way to do it.

In perl, I can just call `$hash{$v1}{$v2}{$v3}..{$vN} = something` because hash not defined can be created by default.

Comment: Unless you need to access the intermediate hashes, nested hash is a bad design here. I would go with assigning an array as a key, i.e., `hash[[2012, 12, 12, 4, 3]] = :foo`.

Comment: Or use a `Date` object as key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with sawa's comment. You will probably have many other problems with such approach. However, what you want is possible.

Search for "ruby hash default value".

By default, the default value of Hash entry is `nil`. You can change that, ie:

```
h = Hash.new(5)
```

and now the `h` when asked for non-existing key will return 5, not nil. You can order it to return a new empty array, or new empty hash in a similar way.

But, be careful. It is easy to accidentally SHARE the default instance through all entries.

```
h = Hash.new([]) // default value = Array object, let's name it X
one = h[:dad]  // returns THE SAME object X
two = h[:mom]  // returns THE SAME object X
```

You must be careful to not use the shared-default-instance, and to use operations that will not mutate it. You cannot just

```
h[:mom] << 'thing'
```

as the `h[:brandnewone]` will now return mutated default instance with "thing" inside.

[See here for a good explanation and proper usage examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159370/ruby-hash-default-value-behavior)

or, even better: [example of autovivifying hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130862/717732)

Comment: A common way to avoid the problem you mention is to use a block: `h = Hash.new{[]}`. But your answer is not necessarily clear on how that extends to an arbitrary depth.

Comment: true. I've forgot about the block option. I've just finally found [this answer about auto-vivification](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10130862/717732) what explains how to use that option to produce new hashes recursively.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a helper method, which you might find useful in other contexts:

```
def mfetch(hash, *keys)
  return nil if (keys.empty? || !hash[keys.first]) 
  return hash[keys.first] if keys.size == 1
  k = keys.shift
  raise ArgumentError, "Too many keys" unless hash[k].is_a? Hash
  return mfetch(hash[k], *keys)
end

h = {cat: {dog: {pig: 'oink'}}}    # => {:cat=>{:dog=>{:pig=>"oink"}}} 
mfetch(h, :cat, :dog, :pig)        # => "oink"
mfetch(h, :cat, :dog)              # => {:pig=>"oink"}  
mfetch(h, :cat)                    # => {:dog=>{:pig=>"oink"}} 
mfetch(h, :cow)                    # => nil 
mfetch(h, :cat, :cow)              # => nil 
mfetch(h, :cat, :dog, :cow)        # => nil 
mfetch(h, :cat, :dog, :pig, :cow)  # => ArgumentError: Too many keys
```

If you preferred, you could instead add the method to the Hash class:

```
class Hash
  def mfetch(*keys)
    return nil if (keys.empty? || !hash[keys.first]) 
    return self[keys.first] if keys.size == 1
    k = keys.shift
    raise ArgumentError, "Too many keys" unless self[k].is_a? Hash
    return self[k].mfetch(*keys)
  end
end

h.mfetch(:cat, :dog, :pig)         # => "oink"
```

or if you are using Ruby 2.0, replace `class Hash` with `refine Hash do` to limit the addition to the current class.  It might be convenient to put it in a module to be included.