# What's going on with this hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

1. I make a new hash with a default value of an empty array.

   ```
   h = Hash.new([])
   ```
2. I push a value into the hash where the key is `'a'`.

   ```
   h['a'].push(1243)
   ```
3. `h` is empty.

   ```
   h # => {}
   ```
4. `h['a']` returns the expected value.

   ```
   h['a'] # => [1243]
   ```
5. `h.keys` returns an empty array.

   ```
   h.keys # => []
   ```

If I initialize the hash in step one with `Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}` then expected values are returned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698460/strange-ruby-behavior-when-using-hash-new explains this very well.

Comment: Yes, this is how it works. `Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}` creates a new array when a key is not found, and `Hash.new([])` uses always the same array when any key is not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that all arguments, unlike blocks, are evaluated only once and prior to the method call.

- In step 1, you are assigning a particular array as the default value. This array instance will be used for the default value of `h`. Notice that, since you have not set the default value using a block, calling a key-value pair will not assign that to the hash.
- In step 2, the array instance for the default value is called because `'a'` is not a key of the hash. You are modifying this array instance.
- Steps 3 and 5 are the same thing; since you have not assigned the default value of `h` with a block, a key-value pair that is called is not assigned to the hash.
- In step 4, you are just calling the default value.

Compare your code with this:

```
h = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}
```

which will generate a new array each time a previously-uncalled key is called, and will assign that key-value pair to the hash.

Comment: What does arguments evaluated only once prior to method execution imply?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `<<` operator is appending to the default array itself, instead of working on a copy of it.

```
 [65] pry(main)> hash = Hash.new([])
=> {}
[66] pry(main)> hash["a"] << 0
=> [0]
[67] pry(main)> hash
=> {}
[68] pry(main)> hash["b"]
=> [0]
[69] pry(main)> hash["c"]
=> [0]
```

edit: It's not just the `<<` operator, `Array#push` also pushes to the default array.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this from a different angle. You are calling `push` on an array. Why would calling `push` on an array modify a hash? There is no relationship between arrays and hashes.

What would you expect to happen here:

```
a = []

h = Hash.new(a)

a.push(1234)
```

Would you expect `h` to change? Probably not. But this is *the exact same thing* your code does!

Comment: that's a good way of looking at it, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Cause, when you write `h = Hash.new([])` - you create new hash with `array` as default value for keys that doesn't exist, when you write `h['a'].push(1243)` - you just add a new element to this array and when you try to do someth like:

```
h['b'], h['c'], h['lol'] 
=> [1243]
```

For create new `hash` you just need to:

**1st example:**

```
h = {}
h['a'] = 1243
```

**2nd example**

```
h = Hash.new
h['a'] = 1243
```

Comment: that's true if I use `h['a'] = 1243` but I want to push multiple strings into each key, so it needs to be an array.