# Can someone explain this simple ruby code to me in simple english

Tags: ruby, hash

In terms of Hash default values, what happens in this instance when you pass a block as a default value, such as:

```
hash = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```

I ran the following code:

```
hash[:one] << "uno"
hash[:two] << "dos"  
hash[:three] 
hash[:four]

hash #returns the hash
```

and the output is:

```
{:two=>["dos"], :three=>[], :four=>[], :one=>["uno"]}
```

Can someone please explains what happens in simple English?

Comment: Don't use txtspk in your questions, please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698460/strange-ruby-behavior-when-using-hash-default-value-e-g-hash-new

Comment: See the accepted answer in the linked question - ["What Does Work: The Mutable Way"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28916684/2864740)

Comment: It creates a default value. It simply means for each new key I create make the value an `Array` but please try reading the documentation first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The objective**

Let's start here:

```
h = {}
h[:a] = [] unless h.key?(:a)
h[:a] << 7
```

We create an empty hash `h`. Each value of this hash will be an array of values. We wish to append `7` to the array that is the value of key `:a`. If `h` already has a key `:a`, we have something like `h[:a] #=> [3,5]`, so we just append `7` to that array:

```
h[:a] << 7 #=> [3,5,7]
```

If, however, `h` does not have a key `:a` (so `h[:a] #=> nil`), we first need to set `h[:a]` to an empty array. Hence the need for:

```
h[:a] = [] unless h.key?(:a)
```

If `h` cannot already have a key `:a` with value `nil` (in other words, if no values are intentionally `nil`), we could instead write:

```
h[:a] = [] unless h[:a]
```

**Ruby-like trick**

We can make this more Ruby-like in a couple of ways. The first is:

```
h = {}
(h[:a] ||= []) << 7 #=> [7] 
h #=> {:a=>[7]} 
(h[:a] ||= []) << 9 #=> [7, 9] 
h #=> {:a=>[7, 9]}
```

When Ruby sees:

```
h[:a] ||= []
```

the first thing she does it convert it to:

```
h[:a] = h[:a] || []
```

The steps are therefore as follows:

```
(h[:a] = h[:a] || []) << 7
  #=> (h[:a] = nil || []) << 7
  #=> (h[:a] = []) << 7
  #=> h[:a] << 7
h[:a] #=> [7]    
(h[:a] = h[:a] || []) << 9
  #=> (h[:a] = [7] || []) << 9
  #=> (h[:a] = [7]) << 9
  #=> h[:a] << 9
h[:a] #=> [7,9]
```

**Ruby-like default value for hash**

The second more Ruby-like way is equivalent to the first, but implemented by defining a *default value* for the hash. If a hash `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value.  Does this also change the hash? Let's put off the question for the moment.

The docs for [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) explain that there are two ways to define a default value.

**Wrong default value**

The first, for making the default value an empty array, is:

```
h = Hash.new([]) #=> {}
```

so if we now write:

```
h[:a] #=> []
```

this returns the default value (`[]`). It does not alter the hash:

```
h #=> {}
```

We may be tempted to write:

```
h[:a] << 7
  #=> [] << 7 => [7]
```

(`h[:a]` returns the default value because there is no key `:a`.) As you see, this does not alter the hash, it just returns an array `[7]` which is not attached to anything, so is garbage-collected.

Now let's try this:

```
(h[:a] = h[:a]) << 7
  #=> (h[:a] = []) << 7 => [7]
h #=> {:a=>[7]} 
(h[:a] = h[:a]) << 9
  #=> (h[:a] = [7]) << 9 => [7, 9] 
h #=> {:a=>[7, 9]}
```

So far, so good, but there's a problem:

```
(h[:b] = h[:b]) << 11 #=> [7, 9, 11] 
h #=> {:a=>[7, 9, 11], :b=>[7, 9, 11]} 
(h[:b] = h[:b]) << 13 #=> [7, 9, 11, 13] 
h #=> {:a=>[7, 9, 11, 13], :b=>[7, 9, 11, 13]}
```

As you see, there is just *one* default empty array.

**Right default value**

Fortunately, there is another way to specify a default array: by giving `Hash#new` a block. (We've finally reached the point of the question.)

If the hash `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` invokes the block. The block has two block variables, `h` and `k`. You can do *whatever you want* in the block. For example:

```
@a = 3
h = Hash.new { |h,k| @a = 7 }
h[:a] #=> 7
h     #=> {}
@a    #=> 7
```

Now I doubt very much that you'd want to do this, but you could. For the present problem you want the value of a new key to be an empty array:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

(Be careful with this. If we executed:

```
puts h[:a]
  #=> []
```

we'd then have

```
h #=> { :a=>[] }
```

)

So:

```
h[:a] << 7
```

first invokes the block, because `h` does not have a key `k`, so we now have:

```
{ :a=>[] }[:a] << 7
h #=> { :a=>[7] }
```

Now when we execute:

```
h[:a] << 9
h #=> {:a=>[7, 9]}
```

the block is not called, because `h` has a key `:a`.

That's about it. Any questions?

Comment: Wow this was a really comprehensive explanation! You really went beyond the call of duty for me and I thoroughly appreciate that! I am forever indebted to you! Thanks once again! It all makes sense now! Lightbulb moment!!!!!

Comment: I am glad to help. Lightbulb moments are great, eh?