# What is happening with this default hash?

Tags: ruby, hashmap, defaultdict

I have the following examples:

```
a = Hash.new([])
a[2][1] = 10
a[2] # => [nil, 10]
a # => {}
```

Why is the default hash not modified? How are the keys not able to be found? Why can't I see or iterate over any keys, but can call them via their index?

Comment: This question was asked too many time.. But to answer you `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }`

Comment: explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698460/strange-behavior-when-using-hash-default-value-e-g-hash-new

Comment: I am not sure if it is a duplicate, and I can't find a good answer in the linked question. So I answer here: You are modifying the default array, but that default array itself is never assigned as a value of the original hash under any key. What you see with `a[2]` is not the `2`-key value of `a`, but merely the default value of `a`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @sawa Thanks for the additional explanation.

Comment: @sawa Myself only answers to such questions many times, but not able to find the link :)