# Create a hash out of an array where the values are the indices of the elements

Tags: ruby

I have an array and I want to create a hash whose keys are the elements of the array and whose values are (an array of) the indices of the array. I want to get something like:

```
array = [1,3,4,5]
... # => {1=>0, 3=>1, 4=>2, 5=>3}

array = [1,3,4,5,6,6,6]
... # => {1=>0, 3=>1, 4=>2, 5=>3, 6=>[4,5,6]}
```

This code:

```
hash = Hash.new 0
array.each_with_index do |x, y|
  hash[x] = y
end
```

works fine only if I don't have duplicate elements. When I have duplicate elements, it does not.

Any idea on how I can get something like this?

Comment: The return value `{1=>[0], 3=>[1], 4=>[2], 5=>[3], 6=>[4,5,6]}` would be easier to compute and I think you'd also find it more convenient for further processing. Also, please don't be vague about what you want. For example, rather than, "something like", write, "the following".

Comment: Try `array.each_with_index.inject(Hash.new([])) { |acc, (x, i)| acc.merge({x => acc[x] + [i]}) }`, it may be a better fit, as suggested by Cary.

Comment: Note that there are some [caveats to passing `[]` to `Hash.new`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2698460/211563) (though they’re avoided in @Gabriel’s particular snippet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding my two cents:

```
array = [1,3,4,5,6,6,6,8,8,8,9,7,7,7]

hash = {}
array.map.with_index {|val, idx| [val, idx]}.group_by(&:first).map do |k, v|
  hash[k] = v[0][1] if v.size == 1
  hash[k] = v.map(&:last) if v.size > 1
end

p hash #=> {1=>0, 3=>1, 4=>2, 5=>3, 6=>[4, 5, 6], 8=>[7, 8, 9], 9=>10, 7=>[11, 12, 13]}
```

It fails with duplicated element not adjacent, of course.

This is the expanded version, step by step, to show how it works.

The basic idea is to build a temporary array with pairs of value and index, then work on it.

```
array = [1,3,4,5,6,6,6]

tmp_array = []
array.each_with_index do |val, idx|
  tmp_array << [val, idx]
end
p tmp_array #=> [[1, 0], [3, 1], [4, 2], [5, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6]]

tmp_hash = tmp_array.group_by { |e| e[0] }
p tmp_hash #=> {1=>[[1, 0]], 3=>[[3, 1]], 4=>[[4, 2]], 5=>[[5, 3]], 6=>[[6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6]]}

hash = {}
tmp_hash.map do |k, v|
  hash[k] = v[0][0] if v.size == 1
  hash[k] = v.map {|e| e[1]} if v.size > 1
end

p hash #=> {1=>1, 3=>3, 4=>4, 5=>5, 6=>[4, 5, 6]}
```

It can be written as one line as:

```
hash = {}
array.map.with_index.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| v.size == 1 ? hash[k] = v[0][1] : hash[k] = v.map(&:last) }
p hash
```

Comment: Why `map!` instead of `map` at the start?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, yes. Why? Actually it is not needed. I updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the logic to special-case the situation when the key already exists, turning it into an array and pushing the new index:

```
arr = %i{a a b a c}

result = arr.each.with_object({}).with_index do |(elem, memo), idx|
  memo[elem] = memo.key?(elem) ? [*memo[elem], idx] : idx
end

puts result
# => {:a=>[0, 1, 3], :b=>2, :c=>4}
```

It's worth mentioning, though, that whatever you're trying to do here could possibly be accomplished in a different way ... we have no context. In general, it's a good idea to keep key-val data types uniform, e.g. the fact that values here can be numbers or arrays is a bit of a code smell.

Also note that it doesn't make sense to use `Hash.new(0)` here unless you're intentionally setting a default value (which there's no reason to do). Use `{}` instead

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For context Im just doing some problems, this one is to find the indices of elements in an array that sum to a given number.

Comment: @Strobes hmm well it's like Cary said in a comment .. it's better to make all values arrays

Comment: There’s nothing un-idomatic about `Hash.new(0)`, generally. It’s just that the O.P. made no use of the default value in their code, which makes it wholly unnecessary in that context.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall ah ok, I had a brain fart and forgot what the argument did. Edited answer.

Comment: Small quibble to the comments - I don't think the use of Hash.new(0) is "unnecessary" here - it's explicitly incorrect.  You could do this with Hash.new(0) in place of {} and you'd get the same "answer" when you inspect the hash.  Where it suddenly becomes wrong is when you ask for result[:d], which should be giving you the location of the symbol :d in the array.  The hash created with a default of 0 will dutifully report that result[:d] is 0, which is almost certainly not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are prepared to accept

```
{ 1=>[0], 3=>[1], 4=>[2], 5=>[3], 6=>[4,5,6] }
```

as the return value you may write the following.

```
array.each_with_index.group_by(&:first).transform_values { |v| v.map(&:last) }
  #=> {1=>[0], 3=>[1], 4=>[2], 5=>[3], 6=>[4, 5, 6]}
```

The first step in this calculation is the following.

```
array.each_with_index.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {1=>[[1, 0]], 3=>[[3, 1]], 4=>[[4, 2]], 5=>[[5, 3]], 6=>[[6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6]]}
```

This may help readers to follow the subsequent calculations.

I think you will find this return value generally more convenient to use than the one given in the question.

Here are a couple of examples where it's clearly preferable for all values to be arrays. Let:

```
h_orig = { 1=>0,   3=>1,   4=>2,   5=>3,   6=>[4,5,6] }
h_mod    { 1=>[0], 3=>[1], 4=>[2], 5=>[3], 6=>[4,5,6] }
```

*Create a hash `h` whose keys are unique elements of `array` and whose values are the numbers of times the key appears in the array*

```
h_mod.transform_values(&:count)
  #=> {1=>1, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>3}
h_orig.transform_values { |v| v.is_a?(Array) ? v.count : 1 }
```

*Create a hash `h` whose keys are unique elements of `array` and whose values equal the index of the first instance of the element in the array.*

```
h_mod.transform_values(&:min)
  #=> {1=>0, 3=>1, 4=>2, 5=>3, 6=>4}
h_orig.transform_values { |v| v.is_a?(Array) ? v.min : v }
```

In these examples, given `h_orig`, we could alternatively convert values that are indices to arrays containing a single index.

```
h_orig.transform_values { |v| [*v].count }
h_orig.transform_values { |v| [*v].min }
```

This is hardly proof that it is generally more convenient for all values to be arrays, but that has been my experience and the experience of many others.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer 