# How to read CSV data into a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv, hash

Given this CSV file:

```
date,name,st,code,num
2020-03-25,AB,53,2585,130
2020-03-26,AB,53,3208,151
2020-03-26,BA,35,136,1
2020-03-27,BA,35,191,1
```

I want to create the following hash with the given data:

```rb
{:AB=>[["2020-03-25", "2585"], ["2020-03-26", "3208"]], :BA=>[["2020-03-26", "136"], ["2020-03-27", "191"]]}
```

I tried this:

```rb
require 'csv'
h=Hash.new([])
CSV.foreach('file.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  h[row['st']] << [[row['date'], row['code']]]
end
```

but all I get is an empty hash `h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first create the CSV file.

```
str =<<~_
date,name,st,code,num
2020-03-25,AB,53,2585,130
2020-03-26,AB,53,3208,151
2020-03-26,BA,35,136,1
2020-03-27,BA,35,191,1
_
```

```
FName = 't'
File.write(FName, str)
  #=> 120
```

Now we can simply read the file line-by-line, using [CSV::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach), which, without a block, returns an enumerator, and build the hash as we go along.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach(FName, headers: true).
  with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |row,h|
    h[row['name'].to_sym] << [row['date'], row['code']]
end  
  #=> {:AB=>[["2020-03-25", "2585"], ["2020-03-26", "3208"]],
  #    :BA=>[["2020-03-26", "136"], ["2020-03-27", "191"]]}
```

I've used the method [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) with a block to create a hash `h` such that if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` causes `h[k] #=> []`. That way, `h[k] << 123`, when `h` has no key `k` results in `h[k] #=> [123]`.

Alternatively, one could write:

```
CSV.foreach(FName, headers: true).with_object({}) do |row,h|
    (h[row['name'].to_sym] ||= []) << [row['date'], row['code']]
end
```

One could also use a *converter* to convert the values of `name` to symbols, but some might see that as over-kill here:

```
CSV.foreach(FName, headers: true,
  converters: [->(v) { v.match?(/\p{Alpha}+/) ? v.to_sym : v }] ).
  with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |row,h|
    h[row['name']] << [row['date'], row['code']]
end
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I don't recall using `each_with_object` before, i need to read its documentation.

Comment: I initially gave an answer that treated the CSV file as an ordinary text file. I had second thoughts about that, however, mainly because it would break if the columns were rearranged and might break if new fields were added or unused fields were removed.

Comment: Also, one set of CSV data _may_ span multiple lines :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to read a CSV file as a text file or whatever, you can use the CSV file as you intended and address the actual issues at hand.

There are three issues here:

1. This won't work:

   ```
   h = Hash.new([])
   ```

   use this instead:

   ```
   h = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = [] }
   ```

   See "[Strange, unexpected behavior (disappearing/changing values) when using Hash default value, e.g. Hash.new([])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698460/strange-unexpected-behavior-disappearing-changing-values-when-using-hash-defa/28916684#28916684)" as @jack commented.
2. You need `headers: true` because the first row is a headers row in your case.
3. You are only pushing to the values array. You need to overwrite it like:

   ```
   h[row['name']] = h[row['name']] << [row['date'], row['code']]
   ```

This will work for you:

```
require 'csv'
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }

CSV.foreach('file.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  h[row['name']] = h[row['name']] << [row['date'], row['code']]
end

h.transform_keys(&:to_sym)

#=> {:AB=>[["2020-03-25", "2585"], ["2020-03-26", "3208"]], :BA=>[["2020-03-26", "136"], ["2020-03-27", "191"]]}
```