# Running Hash.new([]) does what you expect but not in the way you expect it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

So, I want to create a hash where any keys become arrays without having to separately declare them.

I therefore use

```
foo = Hash.new([])
=> {}
```

Then I can add items to keys that haven't been previously declared

```
foo[:bar] << 'Item 1'
=> ['Item 1']
```

There's just something odd about doing this. As when I call

```
foo
=> {}
```

to view the hash, it is empty. Even running

```
foo.keys
=> []
```

shows that it's empty.
However, if I run

```
foo[:bar]
=> ['Item 1']
```

Please make it make sense.

Comment: Also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698460/strange-unexpected-behavior-disappearing-changing-values-when-using-hash-defa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo = Hash.new([])` sets the default value of a not existed key to an array. Here`foo[:bar] << 'Item 1'` the `:bar` key doesn't exist, so `foo` uses an array to which you add a new element. By doing so you mutate the default value because the array is provided to you by a reference.

```rb
> foo = Hash.new([])
=> {}
> foo.default
=> []
```

If you call any not defined key on your hash you'll get this array:

```rb
> foo[:bar] << 'Item 1'
=> ["Item 1"] 
> foo[:foo]
=> ["Item 1"]
```

To achieve your goal you should return a new array every time. It's possible by passing a block to `Hash.new`, the block will be executed every time you access a not defined key:

```rb
> foo = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
=> {}
> foo[:bar] << 'Item 1'
=> ["Item 1"]
> foo[:bar]
=> ["Item 1"]
> foo.keys
=> [:bar]
> foo[:foo]
=> []
> foo[:foo] << 'Item 2'
=> ["Item 2"]
> foo
=> {:bar=>["Item 1"], :foo=>["Item 2"]}
```

[Here is the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Hash.html).

Comment: Friend found a resource I should have located earlier on this too.
https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/new/class

Comment: @bubbaspaarx better refer to the official and more recent docs at https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/Hash.html or https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html – it contains many examples including `Hash.new([])` (as a counter-example)

Comment: I add a link to the documentation