# Building Hash by grouping array of objects based on a property of the items

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm wondering if there is a more canonical way to do this in ruby 1.9

I have an array with a bunch of objects and I want to group them into a Hash using a property of each object in the array.

**Very** simplified example:

```
> sh = {}
 => {} 
> aers = %w(a b c d ab bc de abc)
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "ab", "bc", "de", "abc"] 
> aers.each do |aer|
>     sh[aer.size] = [] if sh[aer.size].nil?
>     sh[aer.size] << aer
>   end
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "ab", "bc", "de", "abc"] 
> sh
 => {1=>["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2=>["ab", "bc", "de"], 3=>["abc"]}
```

I tried this, but its output is wrong (as you can see):

```
 sh = Hash.new([])
 => {} 
> aers.each do |aer|
>     sh[aer.size] << aer
>   end
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "ab", "bc", "de", "abc"] 
> sh
 => {}
```

Comment: And the reason your code isn't working as expected is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698460/strange-ruby-behavior-when-using-hash-new and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552579/ruby-method-array-not-updating-the-array-in-hash (quite a common pitfall in Ruby).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ruby has anticipated your need, and has got you covered with [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001497):

```
irb(main):001:0> aers = %w(a b c d ab bc de abc)
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "ab", "bc", "de", "abc"]

irb(main):002:0> aers.group_by{ |s| s.size }
#=> {1=>["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2=>["ab", "bc", "de"], 3=>["abc"]}
```

In Ruby 1.9, you can make this even shorter with:

```
irb(main):003:0> aers.group_by(&:size)
#=> {1=>["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2=>["ab", "bc", "de"], 3=>["abc"]}
```

Comment: This is why Ruby is so cool; It knows what we want even before we do.

Comment: Please not that in 1.8 symbol to proc is much slower than just using the block. http://confreaks.net/videos/427-rubyconf2010-zomg-why-is-this-code-so-slow check 31:18. In 1.9 they are not differences in performance.

Answer (score 3):

Phrogz is correct, group_by is there for the taking. Your code contains one of ruby's gotcha's.

```
aers = %w(a b c d ab bc de abc)
sh = Hash.new([]) # returns the _same_ array everytime the key is not found. 
# sh = Hash.new{|h,v| h[v] = []}  # This one works
p sh, sh.default

aers.each do |aer|
  sh[aer.size] << aer  #modifies the default [] every time
end
p sh, sh.default
p sh[5]
```

Output

```
{}
[]
{}
["a", "b", "c", "d", "ab", "bc", "de", "abc"]
["a", "b", "c", "d", "ab", "bc", "de", "abc"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this by chaining methods... which might only be of academic interest for this problem, but is still a good technique to be familiar with.

```
irb(main):017:0> sh = {}
=> {}
irb(main):018:0> aers.collect{|k| k.size}.uniq!.each{|k| sh[k] = aers.select{|j| j.size == k}}
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):019:0> sh
=> {1=>["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2=>["ab", "bc", "de"], 3=>["abc"]}
irb(main):020:0>
```