# Weird behavior on new (nested) Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Why both pieces of code are not printing the same thing. I was intending the first piece to produce the output of the second

```
a=Array.new(5,Array.new(3))
for i in (0...a[0].length)
  a[0][i]=2
end
p a
```

> # this prints [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]*

```
a=Array.new(5).map{|d|d=Array.new(3)}
for i in (0...a[0].length)
  a[0][i]=2
end
p a
```

> # this prints [[2, 2, 2], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]

Comment: There is no need to assign to `d` in your block. It should read `...map{|d| Array.new(3)}`.

Comment: @meagar: No need for `|d|` at all...

Comment: Can you explain what *precisely* is unclear to you about the documentation of `Array::new`? That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't fall into the same trap as you did. Please, help making the world a better place!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one

```
a=Array.new(5,Array.new(3))
```

Creates an array that contains the same array object within it five times.  It's kinda like doing this:

```
a = []
b = a
a[0] = 123
puts b[0] #=> 123
```

Where this one:

```
a=Array.new(5).map{ Array.new(3) }
```

Creates a new 3 item array for each item in the parent array.  So when you alter the first item it doesn't touch the others.

This is also why you shouldn't really use the `Array` and `Hash` constructor default arguments, as they don't always work they way you might expect.

Comment: Thanks. Why the default new operator acts so weird... kinda perplexing :(

Comment: Would be a good idea to mention that `Array.new(5){Array.new(3)}` is what the OP probably wanted to do.

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune, can you elaborate a bit on why it is that?

Comment: [[nil]*3]*5 is doing the same thing as a=Array.new(5,Array.new(3))~~~ This is really annoying. How come? Any explanations?

Comment: Because that's how Ruby works. The array class defines a `*` operator. The `*` operator, when passed an integer `N`, produces `N` copies of the array, in an array. `[3] * 3` gives you `[3,3,3]`. You've wrapped that in `[]`, so you have `[[3,3,3]]`. Now you're multiplying the *outer* array by 5, so you get 5 copies of its first element, `[3,3,3]`, so you wind up with `[[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]`.

Comment: I hope StackOverflow would provide Like button like Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.new(5,Array.new(3))
```

In the first example, your array contains 5 references to the same array. You create a single instance of an array with `Array.new(3)`, a reference to which is used for each of the 5 arrays you initialize. When you modify `a[0][0]`, you're also modifying `a[1][0]`, `a[2][0]`, etc. They are all references to the same array.

```
Array.new(5).map{ |d| Array.new(3) }
```

In the second example, your array contains 5 different arrays. Your block is invoked 5 times, `Array.new(3)` is invoked 5 times, and 5 different arrays are created. `a[0]` is a different array than `a[1]`, etc.

Comment: Unnecessary for what? This is a question about the behaviour of that specific line of code. Necessary or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry. So let me suggest an improvement: `Array.new(5){Array.new(3)}` is what the OP probably wanted.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the OP wanted, I wasn't trying to *correct* their code, I was trying *explain* it like he asked me to.

Answer (score 1):

The following are equivalent:

```
Array.new(5,Array.new(3))

[Array.new(3)] * 5

inside = Array.new(3); [inside, inside, inside, inside, inside]
```

They will all produce an array containing the same array. I mean the *exact same* object. That's why if you modify its contents, you will see that new value 5 times.

As you want independent arrays, you want to make sure that the "inside" arrays are not the same object. This can be achieved in different ways, for example:

```
Array.new(5){ Array.new(3) }

5.times.map { Array.new(3) }

Array.new(5).map { Array.new(3) }

# or dup your array manually:
inside = Array.new(3); [inside.dup, inside.dup, inside.dup, inside.dup, inside]
```

Note that the `Array.new(5, [])` form you used first doesn't copy the `obj` for you, it will reuse it. As that's not what you want, you should use the block form `Array.new(5){ [] }` which will call the block 5 times, and each time a new array is created.

The `Hash` class also has two constructors and is [even more tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552579/ruby-method-array-not-updating-the-array-in-hash).