# Hash.new([]) does not behave as expected

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby method Array#<< not updating the array in hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552579/ruby-method-array-not-updating-the-array-in-hash)
>   [Strange ruby behavior when using Hash.new([])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698460/strange-ruby-behavior-when-using-hash-new)

I've been doing [Koans](http://www.rubykoans.com/) which is great, and as I go along I find no major trouble, but I stumbled upon this, and can't make any sense out of it:

```
    def test_default_value_is_the_same_object
        hash = Hash.new([])

        hash[:one] << "uno"
        hash[:two] << "dos"

        assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:one]   # But I only put "uno" for this key!
        assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:two]   # But I only put "dos" for this key!
        assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:three] # I didn't shove anything for :three!

        assert_equal true, hash[:one].object_id == hash[:two].object_id 
    end
```

All the tests are passing (I just looked at the error which helped me guess the right assertions to write).

The last assert, ok, they both were not initialized so their values have got to have the same object ID since they both take the default.

**I don't understand why the default value was altered**, I'm not even entirely sure that's what happened.

I tried it out in IRB, thinking maybe some tampering on Hash/Array was done to make me crazy, but I get the same result.

I first thought `hash[:one] << "uno"` would imply `hash` to become `{ one: ["uno] }`, but it remains `{ }`.
Although I'm guessing `<<` only calls `push`, and new keys are only added when you use the `=` sign

Please tell me what I missed.

**EDIT:** I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: There is only *one* array: the value (`[]`) is evaluated *before* the `new` method is called. Try the "default form" that takes a block (to create a *new* array for real each time the block is yielded/called). I am sure this is a duplicate ..

Comment: Yeah, got bitten by this a couple of times too :)

Comment: @pst could you elaborate? I'm not sure I'm following. And I didn't find any similar questions in SO/Google/Duckduckgo but I can always miss stuff ;)

Comment: @pst it is weird because my hash remains empty, but in the question you linked, his hash gets populated. Maybe it was modified in Ruby since?

Comment: Mmmmh maybe I'm getting it: is it because since we didn't add they key to the hash, `hash[:whatever]` returns the default value of `[]` and that value is modified by `<<` (which is really a `push`, so does not call `=`) ?

Comment: @Baboon: Yes, that's why. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the default argument for a Hash, the same object is used for all keys that have not been explicitly set. This means that only *one* array is being used here, the one you passed into `Hash.new`. See below for evidence of that.

```
>> h = Hash.new([])
=> {}
>> h[:foo] << :bar
=> [:bar]
>> h[:bar] << :baz
=> [:bar, :baz]
>> h[:foo].object_id
=> 2177177000
>> h[:bar].object_id
=> 2177177000
```

The weird thing is that as you found, if you inspect the hash, you'll find that it is empty! This is because only the default object has been modified, no keys have yet been assigned.

Fortunately, there is another way to do default values for hashes. You can provide a default block instead:

```
>> h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
=> {}
>> h[:foo] << :bar
=> [:bar]
>> h[:bar] << :baz
=> [:baz]
>> h[:foo].object_id
=> 2176949560
>> h[:bar].object_id
=> 2176921940
```

When you use this approach, the block gets executed *every  time* an unassigned key is used, and it is provided the hash itself and the key as an argument. By assigning the default value within the block, you can be sure that a new object will get created for each distinct key, and that the assignment will happen automatically. This is the idiomatic way of creating a "Hash of Arrays" in Ruby, and is generally safer to use than the default argument approach.

That said, if you're working with immutable values (like numbers), doing something like `Hash.new(0)` is safe, as you'll only change those values by re-assignment. But because I prefer to keep fewer concepts in my head, I pretty much use the block form exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
h = Hash.new(0)
h[:foo] += 1
```

you are directly modifying `h`. `h[:foo] += 1` is the same as `h[:foo] = h[:foo]+1`. `h[:foo]` is being assigned `0+1`.

When you do

```
h = Hash.new([])
h[:foo] << :bar
```

you are modifying `h[:foo]` which is `[]`, which is the default value of `h` but is not a value to any key of `h`. After that `[]` becomes `[:bar]`, the default value of `h` becomes `[:bar]`, but that is not the value for `h[:foo]`.