# Marshal ruby hash with default proc - remove the default proc?

Tags: ruby, hash, marshalling

I've got a Hash with a default proc that I'd like to Marshal to a file, but the default proc prevents me from doing that.

Rather than writing my own `_dump` and `_load` methods, is it possible instead to remove the default proc instead? At the point where I'm Marshalling I'm never going to need the default proc again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just reset the default:

```
h.default = nil
```

More explicitly:

```
def dumpable_hash(h)
  return h unless h.default_proc
  copy = h.clone  
  copy.default = nil # clear the default_proc
  copy
end
```

In Ruby 2.0, you [can](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4234) also write `h.default_proc = nil` if you prefer. Available for all Rubies with `require 'backports/2.0.0/hash/default_proc'`.

Comment: Turns out `h.default = nil` clears the default proc -- that's all I needed. Thanks!

Comment: It's also possible to dump hashes that have a default value object, such as `Hash.new(42)`. Not that I like having default value objects unless they're immutable.

Answer (score 6):

In case you would want to have a copy without defaults, the simplest way -

```
Hash[hash_with_defaults]
```

Comment: This also is useful if `hash_with_defaults` is frozen and you can't change `default` or `default_proc`.