# Actual Hash getting modified when copy is modified in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to copy a Hash, and then later modifying the copy of hash. But when I compare the copy with the original one, even the original hash value is getting modified.
I have tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3818683/3863146):

```
def deep_copy(o)
  Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(o))
end

h1 = {:a => 'foo'}
h2 = deep_copy(h1)
h1[:a] << 'bar'
p h2
```

I have also tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3818683/3863146):

```
def dumpable_hash(h)
  return h unless h.default_proc
  copy = h.clone  
  copy.default = nil # clear the default_proc
  copy
end
```

Hash object(which I want to copy and keep its original unmodified):

```
@original = {0=>{0=>[0, 4, 5, 6], 2=>[3, 7], 1=>[1, 2]}, 1=>{0=>[0, 4, 5, 6], 2=>[1], 1=>[2, 3, 7]}, 2=>{0=>[0, 4, 6], 1=>[1, 2, 5], 2=>[3, 7]}, 3=>{0=>[0, 4], 2=>[1, 2, 3, 6, 7], 1=>[5]}, 4=>{0=>[4], 2=>[1, 5], 1=>[2, 3, 6, 7, 0]}, 5=>{1=>[0, 1, 2, 5], 2=>[3, 6, 7], 0=>[4]}, 6=>{1=>[0, 1, 2, 5, 4], 2=>[3, 6, 7], 0=>[]}}
```

Tried copying the original into another object, using the given answer also.

Method used for updating its clone,

```
 #outer loop
 (1..5).each do |i|   
 #assigning original to another object in every loop
 copy = @original.clone
       (-6..0).each do |row|                    
            if copy[row.abs][0].include? k
                copy[row.abs][0] -= [k]
                copy[row.abs][1] += [k]
                puts "row #{row.abs}, col #{k}"
                break
            end
        end
    end
```

When the loop is over both the `original` and `copy` are updated.
Please help, I have been trying this from an hour now.

Comment: Which version of ruby (or irb?) are you using? I've tried your deep_copy() example with ruby versions 1.9.3, 2.0, and 2.3, and I don't see any problem.  Perhaps you could also be more explicit about the problem you're seeing.

Comment: I am still unable to fix it, I guess it is because of nested hash.

Comment: @peak, please check the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to copy one hash to another you can do it just like this. Then you can manipulate the copied hash or even do it in the loop. And then manipulate the copied hash it for your task. In here it copies the key-value pair for the hash,

```
@original = {0=>{0=>[0, 4, 5, 6], 2=>[3, 7], 1=>[1, 2]}, 1=>{0=>[0, 4, 5, 6], 2=>[1], 1=>[2, 3, 7]}, 2=>{0=>[0, 4, 6], 1=>[1, 2, 5], 2=>[3, 7]}, 3=>{0=>[0, 4], 2=>[1, 2, 3, 6, 7], 1=>[5]}, 4=>{0=>[4], 2=>[1, 5], 1=>[2, 3, 6, 7, 0]}, 5=>{1=>[0, 1, 2, 5], 2=>[3, 6, 7], 0=>[4]}, 6=>{1=>[0, 1, 2, 5, 4], 2=>[3, 6, 7], 0=>[]}}
copy = Hash.new
@original.each do |k, v|
   copy[k] = v.dup    
end
p copy #prints the copied hash
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked by copying the hash using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do deep_dup here to completely separate one hash content from another.

```
h1 = {a: "foo"}
h2 = h1.deep_dup
h2[:a] << "bar"
puts h2   #returns {:a => "foobar"}
puts h1   # returns {:a => "foo"}
```

Comment: If I use deep_dup, it says `undefined method \`deep_dup' for #<Hash:0x9d3bea0> (NoMethodError)\``. I am trying to solve a problem in an online coding environment and I can not load any external libraries.

Comment: deep_dup is active support only

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dup`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/dup).

```
h1 = {a:1, b:2}
h2 = h1.dup
h2[:c] = 3
puts h1
{:a=>1, :b=>2} 
puts h2
{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

If you have a nested hash, you can use ActiveSupport [`deep_dup`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_dup).

```
def deep_dup
  each_with_object(dup) do |(key, value), hash|
    hash[key.deep_dup] = value.deep_dup
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the original hash (Appending to h1 hash). Modify the deep copied one and you can see the original is staying as before,

```
def deep_copy(o)
   Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(o))
end
h1 = {:a => 'foo'}
h2 = deep_copy(h1)
h2[:a] << 'bar'
p h2 #prints the cloned one
p h1 #prints the original one
```

See this for futher information about marshaling library [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Marshal.html).

Comment: I get this error, `\`dump': can't dump hash with default proc (TypeError)\``

Comment: can you clarify, on which online coding environment you are getting that?

Comment: Right now I am unable to do this in my local environment, If you can try the above example given by me in the question, because I am unable to implement this. May be I am missing something?

Comment: What is the ruby version that you are using in your local environment?

Comment: It's `ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [i686-linux]`